# Why isn't the Recipient field available for Email Alert List Views?

Tags: list-view, email-alert

I am trying to create a List View for our Email Alerts & the Recipient field is not available to display as a Column. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

In Email Alerts Recipients **need not be always a single** user or contact. It can have multiple users, Group, Role, Related User or Account team, thus it is not possible to display multiple details in list view.

That's only reason Salesforce designed to not keep recipient in list view columns of Email Alert.

Thank You.